# Need to create a button/link to use SSO into ServiceNow

Tags: custom-button, single-sign-on, java

Trying to create button/link to log into ServiceNow using the user's email address:

Basically the link has to be crafted to pass 1) the email address of the person already logged in and 2) a specially crafted string that SN understands that is coming from us.

Here’s the link for me, for example:
https://mastercontroldev.service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=cf&contactEmail=mstambaugh@mastercontrol.com&token=pG9cvH/KLvpCGbjS4pSyY7AD3w4=

There are 3 things passed on the url:
1)  uri –it just directs where to go after the automatic login is processed
2)  contactEmail – the email address of the user (so is mstambaugh@mastercontrol.com when I’m logged in, but would be specific to the user).  This is how SN knows who is being signed in on the SN website
3)  token – this is an encrypted version of the value of contactEmail – We have to run a function that encrypts it using some java code and is based on a secret passcode that is also entered on SN.

When SN gets the request, it also encrypts the value of contactEmail with the secret passcode and compares it against the value of token, and if they’re a match, it lets them in as the user associated with contactEmail.  At some point we may have to pass some other exotic information along so that it directs to the specific customer issues, but the first hurdle is just getting the SSO from SF into SN.

So to craft the correct url to get to SN from SF, you’ll have to pull in the email address of the authenticated SF user, then run this encryption stuff to generate the token.  I’m attaching some JAVA code that SN has to “generate the digest token”.

I am just not sure how to create this or if it is possible (I assume that it is). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;


public class DigestTest {

  private static final String MAC_ALG = "HmacSHA1";
  String fKey = "Key";
  public byte[] getDigest(String contactEmail) {

      try {

          byte[] bkey = fKey.getBytes();

          byte[] data = contactEmail.getBytes();

          Mac mac = null;
          try {

              mac = Mac.getInstance(MAC_ALG);

              mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(bkey, MAC_ALG));

          } catch (Exception e) {

              e.printStackTrace();

          }
          byte[] sig = mac.doFinal(data);

          String signature = new String(sig);

          System.out.println("contactEmail:" + contactEmail);
          System.out.println("token:  " + signature);

          return sig;

      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

      return null;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

    DigestTest test = new DigestTest();

    String contactEmail = "$sm_user_value";

    System.out.println("base 64 digest contactEmail: " + encoder.encode(test.getDigest(contactEmail)));



  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the the documentation of the Crypto Class

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Crypto_static_methods.htm

You aren't encrypting per-se, rather generating a HMAC, a Hash based Message Authentication Code based on a shared secret (the 'privateKey' in the example below below).    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code

Code like the below should be what you are looking for.  It's combining the data you want to sign (email address), with a share secret (Private key) and the signing algorithm 'HMACSHA1') to produce a binary output that you then base 64 encode to make it safely a string.

```
 String emailAddress = 'bob@test.com';
 String privateKey = 'Key';
 String token = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(emailAddress), Blob.valueOf(privateKey)));
```

Also, I hope that wasn't your real private key in the message :).

Okay, now you have the digital signature bit, you need to show it to the user.

Since this is apex you are going to either

1. Put the logic into a trigger to calc a value
2. Save the calculated field into a record
3. Build a URL in a formula field
4. Display that url in a page layout.

Or

1. you are going to have to put the value into a controller variable and then build the url in VF that uses this controller variable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. After reading the links you posted and trying a few things, I am still not sure how to make this a clickable link, via button or hyperlink on the account page. Thanks again, I will keep looking while I await your reply!

Comment: It was not the real key, btw... but it was a little too close for comfort. :)

Comment: @Merry you'll need to make a visualforce page with an apex controller to do this - then you can make a button or link pointing to your visualforce page.

Answer (score 2):

ServiceNow supports SAML. If you create ServiceNow app as a SAML service provider (via a Connected app) in SFDC, you'll have your link. Connected app will generate the link and there's no code to write. Ask SFDC folks to add a recipe for ServiceNow to http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Salesforce-SSO-HowTos

Meanwhile, you can try doing it yourself by following

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=SAML_2.0_Web_Browser_SSO_Profile

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help. However, I kicked this over to our webdev guy who ended up getting it to work with Javascript in a standard button. Show-off.

Thanks, again!